# PUT not working properly from my android project but working from Postman

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2, postman, put

I am trying to send a hashmap to the server. I am able to PUT the contents of the hashmap from Postman but I am unable to do the same from my android project. The callback first executes `Onfailure`. On second attempt to send the same data, I get a 409 conflict response.

The stacktrace of the failure:

```
08-21 14:42:19.748 9876-9876/com.example.vishwa.postingdata W/System.err: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $
08-21 14:42:19.750 9876-9876/com.example.vishwa.postingdata W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1401)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:549)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:425)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:161)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
08-21 14:42:19.751 9876-9876/com.example.vishwa.postingdata W/System.err:     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
    at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:119)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:218)
08-21 14:42:19.752 9876-9876/com.example.vishwa.postingdata W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:112)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:141)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The interface:

```
public interface APIService {

@POST("/posts")
@FormUrlEncoded
rx.Observable<Post> savePost(@Field("id") long id,
                             @Field("title") String title,
                             @Field("author") String author);

@PUT("/posts/{id}")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<Post> updatePost(@Path("id") long id,
                      @Field("title") String title,
                      @Field("author") String author);
@DELETE("/posts/{id}")
Call<Post> deletePost(@Path("id") long id);

@PUT("authenticate/create")
Call<HashMap<String,String>> signUpParent(@Body HashMap<String,String> hashMap);
}
```

The function to post:

```
private void PostData(HashMap<String, String> hashMap) {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://coreapi.xxxxx.org:8080/v1/")
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    APIService apiService =retrofit.create(APIService.class);

    apiService.signUpParent(hashMap).enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<HashMap<String, String>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<HashMap<String, String>> call, Response<HashMap<String, String>> response) {
            Integer code=response.code();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"checking the response : "+code,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i("success", "post submitted to API imaginators: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<HashMap<String, String>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("failure", "Unable to submit post to API imaginators.");
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

The request body given in the postman:

```
{
"clientid":"##########",
"email":"IAzMzkaksB8KGT2SLJsol7Xr9Phts/G8",
"first_name":"Eswar",
"last_name":"",
"password":"Dt9keQfZMUY=",
"security_answer":"",
"security_question":"",
"account_type":"learning_pod_app"
}
```

I have found some solutions from these links: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468539/java-io-eofexception-end-of-input-at-line-1-column-1-path-in-gson-parser), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216084/java-io-eofexception-end-of-input-at-line-1-column-1), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49131919/how-to-solve-java-io-eofexception-end-of-input-at-line-1-column-1-path-1-in-ret)...
But they don't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you are sending `JSON` data, So you need to accept and return JSON from the API as well

Comment: Use logcat to show JSON response from the server.

Comment: @sontruongit The code directly executes onfailure, so I am not able to see response in the first attempt itself. In the second it gives, 409 response and the response.body() gives null.

Comment: put all your params of requestbody in a pojo class and then send to the server in place of hashmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method signature to:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@PUT("authenticate/create")
Call<HashMap<String,String>> signUpParent(@Body HashMap<String, String> hashMap);
```

If the response is empty you can use.

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@PUT("authenticate/create")
Call<ResponseBody> signUpParent(@Body HashMap<String, String> hashMap);
```

And give it a try.

Comment: I get this error after trying this approach: "@FieldMap parameters can only be used with form encoding. (parameter #1)". Even with the encoding, I get a 400 response.

Comment: Can you capture a screenshot of the request in Postman with body tab highlighted?

Comment: In Postman, I get a 200 response code but the body doesn't show anything.

Comment: I mean request body not response, before you hit Send button.

Comment: Thank you the second one worked, using the responsebody.

Answer (score 2):

in onFailure method, capture Throweble with Log.e("failure", t.toString());

Then you can find the exact problem with the respond.